# How to pass action with two parameters using Lambda expression to method?

Tags: c#, silverlight, lambda

I have a class that takes an action in it's constructor.

Example:

```
public CustomClass(Action<Path> insert)
{

  // logic here...

}
```

I currently instantiate this class using the following line of code:

```
var custom = new CustomClass((o) => LayoutRoot.Children.Add(o));
```

I want to modify the custom class to include an additional constructor, such as the following:

```
public CustomClass(Action<Path, TextBlock> insert)
{

  // logic here...

}
```

However, my knowledge of lambda expressions is pretty basic, so I can't figure out how to instantiate the custom class, passing two parameters in the action to the new constructor.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: For your future reference, the syntax for different forms of the lambda expression is described in section 7.14 of the C# specification.

Comment: @Eric:  Of course all C# developers will have read the spec already.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order to pass 2 parameters to the action, just define the insert action as an `Action<T,T2>` and when you call it do it like this:

```
var custom = new CustomClass((o,u) => {LayoutRoot.Children.Add(o); somethingElse(u)});
```

Comment: Both constructors weren't meant to be the same - I forgot to format my code snippets as 'code', so when I posted the original question, somehow the constructors appeared identical, so I edited the post to format the snippets as code, and now the constructors should be different.

Anyway, your answer worked, so thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

In Lamba you can pass two parameters as such:

```
(x, y) => { x.DoSomething(); y.DoSomethingElse(); }
```

Comment: yes, but you should also show him how to change his constructor to be able to accept that `Action`

Comment: I believe if it's a compound statement, you'll need curly braces around the body: (x, y) => { x.DoSomething(); y.DoSomethingElse(); }

Comment: Are there a missing pair of { } here?

Comment: @Dathan, sorry it was just edited, it wasn't there when the question was originally asked.

Comment: Ha! @Tony you beated me for a few seconds :P but I didnt forget the {}'s! and he didnt had the right constructor originally ;)

Answer (score 2):

Either you are asking

```
public CustomClass(Action insert, Action insert2) { // logic here... }
```

or

```
 public CustomClass(Action<T1, T2> insert) { // logic here... }
```

The second constructor will take an delegate that receives 2 parameters. So you can do something like

```
CustomClass class = new CustomClass( (x,y) => DoSomething(x,y) );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a lambda expression that takes more than one parameter by surrounding the parameter list with parentheses and comma separate the parameters:

```
var custom = new CustomClass((o, tb) => /* use both params somehow */ );
```

If you need to perform more than one statement in a lambda, you can surround the body of the lambda with braces:

```
var custom = new CustomClass((o, tb) => { o.DoSomething(); tb.DoSomethingElse() } );
```

You can learn more about [lambda syntax here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).