# Can I move my exception code to a handling function. So I don't have to repeat same code

Tags: c#

I currently handle my exceptions like this:

```
try {

        }
        catch (ServiceException ex) {
            ModelState.Merge(ex.Errors);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Trace.Write(e);
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Database access error: " + e.Message);
        }
```

This works but it's the same code I repeat many times. What I am looking for is some suggestion on how I could move this into an external function. I don't necessarily need to move the try block there but at least the other code.

Maybe a function that was passed the Exception and the ModelState (as a reference). Can anyone suggest a clean way that I could code up this function. I'm asking here because almost always someone seems to come up with a solution that I could never have thought of. Thanks Samantha.

Comment: You're handling these exceptions differently though, so I can't see how you are repeating the code? If you mean its being used elsewhere then you can always create a private method that handles your exception operations.

Comment: Yes you can pass the exception to any other function.

Comment: Pass the exception as a parameter to a function? Then you can use that function as many times as you want, only changing the exception thrown.

Comment: yes you can actually highlight the code that you want goto the refactor menu item in VS2010 or 2008 and select Extract to Method... give the method a name hit ok then it will make the call and the method code for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make a method that takes in an Action, and invokes it in a try/catch block:

```
private void RunAndHandleExceptions(Action action)
        {
            try
            {
                action.Invoke();
            }
            catch (ServiceException ex)
            {
                ModelState.Merge(ex.Errors);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Trace.Write(e);
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Database access error: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
```

And call it like this:

```
RunAndHandleExceptions(new Action(() =>
                {
                    //Do some computing
                }));
```

**EDIT**: with a parameter (example, can run in a console program):

```
private static void ParameterizedTask()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action<object>((y) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(y);
        }), 5);
        Thread.Sleep(1500);
    }
//OUTPUT: 5
```

For more info you can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050322/how-to-pass-action-with-two-parameters-using-lambda-expression-to-method) thread.

Comment: You do not need declare new Action. It can be done like this...
RunAndHandleExceptions(() => 
{
//Do some computing
});

Comment: Maybe change it to an extension method for ModelState so the call site looks something like `Model.RanAndHandle(()=>...);` as well?

Comment: This still requires him to catch the two Exceptions in question.  All you are doing is repeating one line instead of several.

Comment: Hello, This answer looks great. If you have a moment can you tell me how to pass a parameter to the action.

Comment: You can use variables from outside the Action. However, if you want to ensure the Action has a parameter of a specific type available, you can use the Action<T>() override.

Comment: What I would like to do is pass two parameters. I'll perhaps open this up as another question. As I want to give credit to the people who helped me here.

Answer (score 2):

(Updated to match the OP's new requirement in comments)

```
private void HandleException(Action<IEnumerable<string>> action, 
  IEnumerable<string> parameters)
{
  try {
    action(parameters);
  }
  catch (ServiceException ex) {
    ModelState.Merge(ex.Errors);
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    Trace.Write(e);
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Database access error: " + e.Message);
  }
}
```

which can be invoked with a lambda for instance:

```
HandleException((parameters) => Console.WriteLine(parameters.FirstOrDefault()), 
                                new string[] {"Pretty safe in this case"});
```

Comment: I need to pass some parameters to my action. Can you show me how I could do this. Maybe just a really simple example where I pass a couple of strings into the code of the action.

Answer (score 1):

Besides passing the the exception to another function as has been suggested in the comments, you could also pass the code to be run as an `Action` to function would then run the action in a try catch.